# NSNotFound comparison not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

Simple one.

I'm using indexOfObject to check if a value is already in an array.

If the value isn't in the array indexOfObject returns the constant NSNotFound.

Why does comparison with > 100000 work:

```
NSInteger indexOfCell = [_selectedCellIndices indexOfObject:cellIndex];

if(indexOfCell > 1000000)
```

but equality with NSNotFound fail:

```
NSInteger indexOfCell = [_selectedCellIndices indexOfObject:cellIndex];

if(indexOfCell == NSNotFound)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? What is the exact value of indexOfObject when nothing is found?

Comment: By fails I mean when checking for an item in the array which doesn't exist the value returned should be NSNotFound (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:) but when the code gets to if(indexOfCell == NSNotFound) the comparison evaluates as False

Comment: Of course, _selectedCellIndices is nil, indexOfCell will be zero.  What value is actually returned?

Comment: Value returned is 2147483647 (in IOS simulator)

Comment: "Value returned is 2147483647". Well, that's NSNotFound.

Comment: Results can't be reproduced.

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting your tests reversed.

Comment: Can't reproduce this with the code sample given here unfortunately.

Comment: _selectedCellIndices is an NSMutableArray. cellIndex is an NSNumber. Equality fails even when _selectedCellIndices has other, none matching entries. _selectedCellIndices is not nil it's been instantiated as [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2147483647 *is* NSNotFound (also known, under certain circumstanced, as -1). There is something wrong with how you are testing whether your test succeeds or fails, because Cocoa itself is behaving exactly as advertised.

```
NSInteger indexOfCell = [[NSArray new] indexOfObject:@""];
NSLog(@"%d", indexOfCell); // some number
NSLog(@"%d", NSNotFound); // the same number
NSLog(@"%d", indexOfCell == NSNotFound); // 1, i.e. YES
```

Try it yourself.

Comment: 2147483647 is NSNotFound on 32bits platform, not 64bits platform

Comment: @BryanChen Pls read what I wrote. I *said* it would also be known as -1. The code that I provided works on both 32-bit and 64-bit (with warnings on the latter, of course). In any case, I have proven that his code cannot be failing in the way he describes it as failing. That's all that matters.

Comment: This helped me get the answer. The problem was it wouldn't let me evaluate expr NSNotFound in the debugger. By using NSLog it was obvious I was doing something stupid.

Comment: I copied the exact code.. and the output is: -1 -1 0

Answer (score 1):

you could use the ContainsObject: method.  Might be easier.

Answer (score -1):

indexOfObject is suppose to be NSUInteger (unsigned) not NSInteger. That is probably screwing up your comparison. Try changing the type to NSUInteger and trying again.

Comment: `NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax` so I can't see any UB here

Comment: Doesn't work with NSUInteger either

Comment: Irrelevant and misleading. Using NSInteger works perfectly well.